# MVC dropdownlist across models

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm linking Users in my data model to Companies such that every user has to belong to 1 (and only 1) company, however, an admin user should be allowed to select a company for the user to belong to when adding, and so should see a dropdownlist that he/she can select a company from.

I've found a couple of pages on adding dropdownlists for collections within the View's model (eg. ice cream flavors for a selection of ice cream) but I haven't found anything on linking across classes like I need to here.

My view is written to look at the User class below (`@model Logan.User`). I had considered adding Companies to that as a sort of comma-delimited list of models but that didn't work...

Here are the relevant classes in my data model:

User:

```
// BaseUser defines common fields such as email address and password
public class User : BaseUser
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
}
```

Company:

```
// BaseObject defines a Primary Key column and columns for auditing
public class Company : BaseObject
{
    public string Companyname { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
    public string LicenseKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime LicenseDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
        Companyname = String.Empty;
        ContactPerson = String.Empty;
        ContactNumber = String.Empty;
        EmailAddress = String.Empty;
        PhysicalAddress = String.Empty;
        LicenseKey = String.Empty;

        Clients = new List<Client>();
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

Basically I'm looking for a dropdownlist that uses the Primary Key as it's value and Companyname as it's text.

In asp.net this list would contain objects that look something like:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlCompanies">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem text="Please select a company" value="0" selected="true" />
        <asp:ListItem text="Foo Company" value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem text="Bar Company" value="2" />
    </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to link my classes in this case to allow for such a dropdownlist to be created?

Comment: It seems like what is being shown in the Companies drop down list should really be controlled by the Roles of the user. An Admin would be able to see a complete list of companies when adding a user. If your environment dictates that the Administrator must also belong to a company, then you could create an Administrators company, users of which are all Admins, but I would avoid this if possible.

Comment: okay but that still doesn't cover how to actually create the drop down list. Planned implementation of the system doesn't include many admin users (really just myself for the foreseeable future) so I'm not too worried, but the dropdown needs data from the Companies table which the View doesn't have. A joint model perhaps?

Comment: You can use multiple models within a single View or you can get the Companies drop down list data using a web service.

Comment: I don't understand your question. How's this dropdownlist different from all other dropdownlists?

Comment: @boosts how to use both models in the view? I think that would probably be easiest

Comment: @Ortund I posted an example of what you are looking for as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ViewModel. A ViewModel is a class specifically for feeding a view with data. In your ViewModel class (say called EditUserViewModel) you can have a User object and a List to populate the dropdown list and a SelectedCompanyID bound to the selected value of the view model.

Here is an example - http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm

You can use the Html.DropDownListFor helper method to create the drop down list and you can have your POST action accept the very same ViewModel class. If you do it correctly the SelectedCompanyID property will be populated with the value from the dropdown list.

Comment: I feel like I could have had the scaffolding take care of this for me if I created my data structures better

Comment: The scaffolding cannot create the viewmodel but if you create the viewmodel the scaffolding can create the view with the DropDownListFor

Comment: When building the select (either via SelectList class in the ViewModel or directly via the helper methods) make sure to specify the text and value properties. Text should be the display string and value should be the id

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different methods of using multiple models per view, but a common one is to take advantage of the ViewData. Your action could look like,

```
    public ActionResult UserAdministration()
    {
        ViewData["Companies"] = // the companies a user can be aligned to
        ViewData["User"] = // the user data
        return View();
    }
```

And within your view, you can access the Companies data by simply using

```
ViewData["Companies"]
```

One method of building a drop down would be

```html
<select id="ddl_companies">
  <option>Select Company </option>
    @foreach (var item in ViewData["Companies"] as List <Company>)
    {         
      <option>@item.Companyname
      </option>            
    }
</select>
```